# how to use CameraInfoManager for stereo camera?

Tags: ros, stereo, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is it possible to use single CameraInfoManager object to get the calibration data for both left and right stereo camera?
It looks from CameraInfoManager that we can get camera calibration parameter for only one camera and not both.
Is there any other message for stereo camera which can get both left and right calibration parameters?

Warm Regards,

pramod

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9947/how-to-use-camerainfomanager-for-stereo-camera?/) by [prbhagwat](https://answers.ros.org/users/108/prbhagwat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2011-05-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-12**:
Could you reword your headline/title into a question? It makes it easier for people to find questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even when using a stereo camera, there is no such thing as a "stereo camera info" message. Instead, the left and right cameras publish each publish their respective camera info. If you are writing a stereo camera driver node, then you should use a separate `CameraInfoManager` for each half. If you want to do your own stereo processing, then you should use the `TimeSynchronizer` class in the `message_filters` package to synchronize the cameras' `image` and `camera_info` topics.

---

Originally posted by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) with karma: 524 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3